# PostgreSQL - select next and previous ids in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple question, suppose we have a table:

```
 id   A   B
 1   Jon  Doe
 2   Foo  Bar
 3   Jon  Doe
 4   Foo  Bar
 5   Jon  Doe
 6   Foo  Bar
 7   Jon  Doe
 8   Foo  Bar
 9   Jon  Doe
 10   Foo  Bar
```

Is there a way to get next and previous 2 ids by passing an id. If I pass 5 as an Id then the query should return 3,4,6,7 as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
x := 5;

SELECT *
FROM
   tbl_name
Where id < x
order by id desc
limit 2
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
   tbl_name
Where id > x
order by id asc
limit 2;
```

Comment: @v0ld3m0rt well, we should add more `order by id`. I edited

Answer (score 1):

an approach with window functions, using lag and lead:

```
select
lag(id,2) over (order by id) before2,
lag(id,1) over (order by id) before1,
id,
LEAD(id,1) over (order by id) next1,
LEAD(id,2) over (order by id) next2
from mytable order by id
```

you have to define, what should happen, selecting the upper or lower boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select t2.id
               from t t2
               where t2.id < 5
               order by t2.id desc
               limit 2
              ) or
      t.id in (select t2.id
               from t t2
               where t2.id > 5
               order by t2.id asc
               limit 2
              );
```